# Enumerate with return type other than string?

Tags: c#, enums

Since enumeration uses integers, what other structure can I use to give me enum-like access to the value linked to the name:

[I know this is wrong, looking for alternative]

```
private enum Project
    {
        Cleanup = new Guid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1"),
        Maintenance = new Guid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2"),
        Upgrade = new Guid("892F865-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C1"),
        Sales = new Guid("A5690E7-1111-4AFB-B44D-1DF3AD66D435"),
        Replacement = new Guid("11E5CBA2-EDDE-4ECA-BDFD-63BDBA725C8C"),
        Modem = new Guid("6F686C73-504B-111-9A0B-850C26FDB25F"),
        Audit = new Guid("30558C7-66D9-4189-9BD9-2B87D11190"),
        Queries = new Guid("9985242-516A-4151-B7DD-851112F562")
    }
```

EDIT 2014-07-20

This is a newer answer to this question. Using the Attribute class with a helper method, define the extra attributes needed on your enum.

```
 public enum MultiValueEnum
    {
        [FooAttribute("alpha", 20d, true)]
        First,
        [FooAttribute("beta", 40.91d, false)]
        Second,
        [FooAttribute("gamma", 1.2d, false)]
        Third,
    }     

  public class FooAttribute : Attribute
            {
                internal FooAttribute(string name, double percentage, bool isGood)
                {
                    this.Name = name;
                    this.Percentage = (decimal)percentage;
                    this.IsGood = isGood;
                }
                public string Name { get; private set; }
                public decimal Percentage { get; private set; }
                public bool IsGood { get; private set; }
            }



  public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
            return type.GetField(name)
                .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                .OfType<TAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

Which makes it this easy:

```
        MultiValueEnum enumVar = MultiValueEnum.First;
        var enumStringValue = enumVar.GetAttribute<FooAttribute>().Name;
        var enumValueDecimal = enumVar.GetAttribute<FooAttribute>().Percentage;
        var enumBool = enumVar.GetAttribute<FooAttribute>().IsGood;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Otherwise you could create a custom Attribute for your enum, which can hold the Guid.

Something alongside these lines:

```
class EnumGuid : Attribute
{
    public Guid Guid;

    public EnumGuid(string guid)
    {
        Guid = new Guid(guid);
    }
}
```

And you'd then use it like so:

```
enum Project
{
    [EnumGuid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1")]
    Cleanup = 1,
    [EnumGuid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2")]
    Maintenance = 2
    // and so forth, notice the integer value isn't supposed to be used, 
    // it's merely there because not assigning any value is a performance overhead.
}
```

And finally you could (I always do this) create an extension for easily getting the guid:

```
static Guid GetEnumGuid(this Enum e)
{
    Type type = e.GetType();

    MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(e.ToString());

    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumGuid),false);
        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            return ((EnumGuid)attrs[0]).Guid;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Enum " + e.ToString() + " has no EnumGuid defined!");
}
```

So in the end all you have to with your enums is:

```
Guid guid = Project.Cleanup.GetEnumGuid();
```

I use this approach to attach descriptions to enums, typically longer strings containing spaces, which thus cannot be used as names.

Comment: This solution will not build for me.
However, if you change the constructor on the EnumGuid to take string and then create the guid from this string it will.
        
public class EnumGuid : Attribute
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; private set; }

        public EnumGuid(String s)
        {
            this.Guid = Guid.Parse(s) ;
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah, it appears you must use primitive types for enum constructors, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859094/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-create-a-attribute-of. However as stated by @Druaka, convert a string to a Guid inside the constructor and all is well.

Answer (score 12):

I've seen this method (struct) used by SubSonic to store Column and Table names.

```
internal struct Project
{
   public static Guid  Cleanup = new Guid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1");
   public static Guid  Maintenance = new Guid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A129EB2");
   public static Guid  Upgrade = new Guid("892F865-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C1");
   public static Guid  Sales = new Guid("A5690E7-1111-4AFB-B44D-1DF3AD66D435");
   public static Guid  Replacement = new Guid("11E5CBA2-EDDE-4ECA-BD63-B725C8C");
   public static Guid  Modem = new Guid("6F686C73-504B-111-9A0B-850C26FDB25F");
   public static Guid  Audit = new Guid("30558C7-66D9-4189-9BD9-2B87D11190");
   public static Guid  Queries = new Guid("9985242-516A-4151-B7DD-851112F562");
}
```

EDIT:- Thanks for commenting on deficiencies in code. In first place it will compile if the Guid strings are not invalid. As for not create instances to access variables yes they need to be **public static**

Comment: Can't access private fields in structs, also cant initialize fields like you do in a struct.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to create instances of this struct, since it acts only as a container

Comment: Well it wont compile for more than 1 reason.

Comment: Make it a static class. This is the same thing as Brushes.Black and so on.

Answer (score 7):

I would probably go the dictionary route on this one.  Have a lookup table basically:

```
public class GuidMapper
{
    private Dictionary<GuidTypes, Guid> mGuidMap = new Dictionary<GuidTypes, Guid>();
    public enum GuidTypes: int
    {
        Cleanup,
        Maintenance,
        Upgrade,
        Sales,
        Replacement,
        Modem,
        Audit,
        Queries
    }

    public GuidMapper()
    {
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Cleanup, new Guid("2ED31640-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF100"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Maintenance, new Guid("39D31D40-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2000"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Upgrade, new Guid("892F8650-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C100"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Sales, new Guid("A5690E70-1111-4AFB-B44D-1DF3AD66D435"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Replacement, new Guid("11E5CBA2-EDDE-4ECA-BDFD-63BDBA725C8C"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Modem, new Guid("6F686C73-504B-1110-9A0B-850C26FDB25F"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Audit, new Guid("30558C70-66D9-4189-9BD9-2B87D1119000"));
        mGuidMap.Add(GuidTypes.Queries, new Guid("99852420-516A-4151-B7DD-851112F56200"));
    }

    public Guid GetGuid(GuidTypes guidType)
    {
        if (mGuidMap.ContainsKey(guidType))
        {
            return mGuidMap[guidType];
        }
        return Guid.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need proper `enum`-like semantics and type-safety then you can use a pattern like this.

(You could flesh it out further if you require extras like conversion operators, `GetUnderlyingType`, `ToString` etc. If you wanted to re-use the pattern for multiple `enum`-like classes with different underlying types then you could move any common code into a generic, abstract base class.)

```
Project x = Project.Cleanup;
Project y = Project.Cleanup;
Project z = Project.Maintenance;

Console.WriteLine(x == y);     // True
Console.WriteLine(x == z);     // False
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);    // 47801daa-7437-4bfe-a240-9f7c583018a4

// this line will cause a compiler error
Console.WriteLine(x == new Guid("47801daa-7437-4bfe-a240-9f7c583018a4"));

// ...

public class Project
{
    private Project(Guid v) { Value = v; }
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }

    public static readonly Project Cleanup =
        new Project(new Guid("47801daa-7437-4bfe-a240-9f7c583018a4"));

    public static readonly Project Maintenence =
        new Project(new Guid("2548a7f3-7bf4-4533-a6c1-dcbcfcdc26a5"));

    public static readonly Project Upgrade =
        new Project(new Guid("ed3c3e73-8e6a-4c09-84ae-7f0876d194aa"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When confronted with this kind of problem I used structs with consts as public members:

```
public struct FileExtensions
{
    public const string ProcessingExtension = ".lck";
    public const string ProcessedExtension = ".xml";
    public const string FailedExtension = ".failed";
    public const string CsvExtension = ".csv";
}
```

Comment: A class will make more sense, given you can derive from it, and extend the constants.

Comment: I wouldn't derive from a class whose only purpose is to contain constant values, since polymorphism wouldn't make much sense. Instead I would keep adding related constants to the same class, or create new ones for new sets of constants.

Comment: @enrico: there are a few benefits, like the parents fields being in scope.

Comment: using  
public const Guid  Cleanup = new Guid("2E43264-BB48-432B-86C4-A2B1114BF1");

in oublic struc I get build error: "cannot have field initialisers in structs." and "System.Guid cannot be declared const"

Comment: Why do people gravitate toward struct for this?

Comment: @Oded: that is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class that just contains constant values.
For example:

```
internal static class Project
{
    public static readonly Guid Cleanup = new Guid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1");
    public static readonly Guid Maintenance = new Guid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2");
    public static readonly Guid Upgrade = new Guid("892F865-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C1");
}
```

This way the class acts simply as a container and object cannot be created from it.

In VB this would be a Module:

```
Friend Module Project
    Public Shared ReadOnly Cleanup As Guid = New Guid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1")
    Public Shared ReadOnly Maintenance As Guid = New Guid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2")
    Public Shared ReadOnly Upgrade As Guid = New Guid("892F865-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C1")
End Module
```

Comment: Here we go still. Static classes cant have instance members!

Answer (score 0):

The enum type can [only support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.71).aspx) the [integral types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx) (except char) as its value.  You could however use something like a Dictionary to do lookups of a a name to a value.

```
Dictionary<Guid> lookup = new Dictionary<Guid>();
lookup["Cleanup"] = new Guid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1");
lookup["Maintenance"] = new Guid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2");
lookup["Upgrade"] = new Guid("892F865-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C1");
// etc...
```

Another alternative is to have a series of readonly values in a static class.

```
public static class Guids
{
  public static readonly Guid Cleanup = new Guid("2ED3164-BB48-499B-86C4-A2B1114BF1");
  public static readonly Guid Maintenance = new Guid("39D31D4-28EC-4832-827B-A11129EB2");
  public static readonly Guid Upgrade = new Guid("892F865-E38D-46D7-809A-49510111C1");
}
```

Comment: Here we go again. Static classes cant have instance members!