# An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ...- Create an attribute of type array

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Here is my custom attribute and a class I'm using it on:

```
[MethodAttribute(new []{new MethodAttributeMembers(), new MethodAttributeMembers()})]
public class JN_Country
{

}

public class MethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MethodAttributeMembers[] MethodAttributeMembers { get; set; }

    public MethodAttribute(MethodAttributeMembers[] methodAttributeMemberses)
    {
        MethodAttributeMembers = methodAttributeMemberses;
    }
}

public class MethodAttributeMembers
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string MethodTitle { get; set; }
}
```

The syntax error, displayed on the first line above:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 48):

This supplements the information Simon already gave.

I found some documentation here: [Attribute parameter types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types):

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (Attribute specification).
> - **Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.** *(emphasis added by me)*
>
> A constructor argument or public field which does not have one of these types, cannot be used as a positional or named parameter in an attribute specification.

The last bullet point explains your syntax error. You've defined a one-dimensional array, but it should only be of primitive types, string, etc. as listed in the previous bullet points.

Comment: strangely `double` is supported `decimal` is not

Comment: Contrary to documentation, using a single-dimensional array of strings also results in the same compiler error. I'm trying `[Values(new string[1] { "1" })] string[] codes` as a method parameter.

Answer (score 28):

Attribute arguments must be compile-time constant. That means that the compiler must be able to "bake in" the values of the arguments when the assembly is compiled. `new ReferenceType()` is not constant - it must be evaluated at runtime to determine what it is.

Interestingly, [this is a little bit flimsy](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/) in that there are some edge cases to that rule. Other than those though, you cannot do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to use static strings but that didn't work so I had to switch to const

Answer (score 0):

Let me add that the compiler can return this error without any particular file or line of code, if your attribute has a constructor that has a parameter that isn't a simple type and you use the constructor (i.e. your non-simple parameter has a default value).

```
[MyAttribute(MySimpleParameter: "Foo")]
public class MyObject
{

}

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string MySimpleProperty { get; set; }

    public MyPropertyClass MyComplexProperty { get; set; }

    public MethodAttribute(string MySimpleParameter, MyPropertyClass MyComplexParameter = null)
    {
        MySimpleProperty = MySimpleParameter;
        MyComplexProperty = MyComplexParameter;
    }
}

public class MyPropertyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
}
```