# How to pass a dynamic variable into the authorize attribute class in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, class-attributes

How to pass a dynamic variable into the authorize attribute class in asp.net mvc?

For Example I have this piece of code, how can I pass a variable like userRoles variable into the Authorize attribute class?

```
private  string userRoles;
private string getuserRoles() 
{
     //Write your code to get userRoles
     userRoles = "admin";
     return "admin";
 }

[Authorize(Roles = object.getuserRoles())]
public ActionResult Admin()
{
       ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();

}
```

My code issues this error

> Error 1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type  C:\Users\Nashat\Downloads\New folder
>   (3)\MvcPWy\Controllers\HomeController.cs  39  28  MvcPWy

So please could anyone help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
    [Authorize(Roles = Roles.UserRoles)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

You have to pass a constant variable for Roles, something like this:

```
public static class Roles
{
    public const string UserRoles = "UserRoles";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: You can't do that.  Have a look at this  [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859094/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-create-a-attribute-of) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look - 
 [An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ...- Create a attribute of type array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859094/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-create-a-attribute-of)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx