# Pass an array as attribute-value

Tags: c#, attributes, nunit

I have a test-method as follows:

```
[TestCase(new string[] { "1", "2", "5" }, Result = true)]
bool AllocateIDsTest1(IEnumerable<string> expected)
{
    var target = ...
    var actual = target.AllocateIDs(expected);

    return actual.SequenceEqual(expected);
}
```

However I get a compiler-error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

Probably the compiler can´t distinguish between the following constructors:

```
TestCase(params object[] args, Named Parameters);
```

and

```
TestCase(object ob1, Named Paramaters);
```

because `new string[] { "1", "2", "5" }` can be resolved to both `params object[]` and `object`.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859321/2528063) I know that a string-array should be possible to pass as compile-constants.

How can I provide an array of strings to a `TestCase`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution using the params-approach:

```
[TestCase("1", "2", "5", Result = true)]
public bool AllocateIDsTest1(params string[] expected)
{
    var target = ...
    var actual = target.AllocateIDs(expected);

    return actual.SequenceEqual(expected);
}
```

Comment: Excellent workaround. Another option is to use TestCaseSource, see the docs.

Comment: Not even a workaround. :-) It's how TestCase is supposed to be used. The compiler error is not because you passed in an array - that's expressly allowed on attributes. It's because you are asking the attribute constructor to dynamically create the array using new. C# doesn't allow that.

Comment: @Charlie So how exactly should assigning an array to an attribute work, when you say "that´s expressly allowed on attributes"? Via a `static` field?